# AngularJS: Ng-repeat breaks "Waves" animation

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

Waves is from here.
http://fian.my.id/Waves/

To add the wave effect, you just have to add the JS and CSS files, then add class="waves-effect waves-button" to the component of your choice, and call Waves.displayEffect();.

Unfortunately, it looks like the angularJS ng-repeat breaks this. There are no errors in the console.

This works:

```
<a href="#" class="waves-effect waves-button">Click Here</a>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 garment" ng-repeat="garment in buypage.garments">
</div>
```

This doesn't:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 garment" ng-repeat="garment in buypage.garments">
              <a href="#" class="waves-effect waves-button">Click Here</a>
</div>
```

**Edit**

Moving  Waves.displayEffect(); inside controller did not fix it.

Comment: Demo, would be nice here.

Comment: The this work and this doesn't work snippets are the same

Comment: I guess that the problem is that when you call Waves.displayEffect(); the elements are not yet rendered. You shoud try to include the call to Waves in a directive.

Comment: @edrian: Re: snippets, thanks!

Comment: @edrian: Moving inside controller didn't work

Answer (score 1):

**Solved**

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="garment in buypage.garments" ng-init="initWaves()">
...
</div>
```

In AngularJS Controller:

```
$scope.initWaves = function(){
  Waves.displayEffect();
}
```